# React keeps saying onChildToggle is not a function why is this?

Tags: reactjs

I have it working in 15 but realized I need it for version 16. My toggle() function inside my Child class is what I think needs fixing. Any help is appreciated. (I don't know how many more details I need to put into this question so it can be submitted. I'm hoping the code speaks for it self)

codepen... https://codepen.io/badbabykosh/pen/pGLYov

js

```
let allData = 
    [
    {
      id:1,
      parent: "Checked Parent",selected:false,
      children:
          [
            {id:2, name:"One Item",selected:false},
            {id:3, name:"Checked Child",selected:false}
          ]
     },
     {
       id:4,
       parent: "Parent",selected:false,
       children:
          [
            {id:5, name:"Child One",selected:false},
            {id:6, name:"Child Two",selected:false}
          ]
     }
    ];

class Application extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return (<CheckboxContainer data={allData} />);
  }
}

class CheckboxContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {    
    let list = this.props.data.map((s) => {
      return (<ParentCheckbox data={s} />);
    });

    return(
      <div>
        {list}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class ParentCheckbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selected: this.props.data.selected,show:true,children:this.props.data.children};
  }

  toggleShow() {
    this.setState({show:!this.state.show});
  }

  //Toggle the state checkbox & nested city checkboxes
  toggle() {
    let newSelectedState = !this.state.selected;
    this.setState({selected:newSelectedState});
    this.toggleCities(newSelectedState);
  }

  // Toggle the state of the cities accordingly: Select / Unselect all cities
  toggleChildren(selected) {
    let children = this.state.children;
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      children[i].selected = selected;
    }
    this.setState({children:children});
  }



  // Update the state checkbox accordingly when cities have been toggled
  onChildToggle(name,selected) {
    // Update the state of the cities accordingly
    let children = this.state.children;
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if(children[i].name === name) {
        children[i].selected = selected;
        break;
      }
    }

    //State checkbox should be selected if >1 city is checked
    let updatedSelectionState = false;
    for(let i = 0; i < children.length;i++) {
      if(children[i].selected) {
        updatedSelectionState = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState({selected:updatedSelectionState,children:children});
  }

  render() {            
    let children;
    if (this.state.show) {
      children = this.state.children.map((child) => {
        return (<Child name={child.name} selected={child.selected} onChildToggle={this.onChildToggle.bind(this)} />);
      });      
    }

    return(
      <div className="parent">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} checked={this.state.selected}></input>
          <h1>{this.props.data.parent}</h1>
        </label>

        <button onClick={this.toggleShow.bind(this)}>{this.state.show ? "Hide" : "Show"}</button>

        <div className='child'>
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.props.onChildToggle(this.props.name,!this.props.selected);
  }

  render() {    
    return(
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.selected} onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}></input>
          <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

css

```
html, body
  height: 100%

body
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  font-family: Helvetica Neue

button
  display: inline-block

h1
  display: inline-block

.child
  margin-left: 10px

.parent 
  margin-bottom: 20px
```

html

```
<div id="app"></app>
```

Comment: right above....

Answer (score 0):

You can have a react component which renders a checkbox and you can reuse it to generate as many checkboxes as you want. You just have to return your label from inside of return function of the react component.

You can also have a component state which can help you track whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

This will be a good starting point.
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Just updated my question. I've got code that's for react15 that I need to run for react 16. Something is wrong with my toggle function in my "child" class.

Comment: updated pen to react 16. code does not work now. forgot to update the pen.

Answer (score 0):

I see only these errors in the console. I am using react and react-dom version 16.0.0
[image: error]

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "expensify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Amritansh",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-modal": "2.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "clappr": "^0.3.1"
  }
}
```

Just add a key to your map function and the above warning will also go away

Comment: added a key to my map function. Still getting "TypeError: this.props.onChildToggle is not a function"

Comment: keep your bind inside the constructor function of your component. this.onChildToggle= this.onChildToggle.bind(this)

Comment: or alternatively you can use babel's ransform-class-properties plugin. I hope your error will be resolved.

Comment: Just switched the codepin to reflect react 16. still getting "this.props.onChildToggle is not a function"...now it is broken in codepen as well.